# Документ с реквизитами, содержащими сумму платежа

Tags: названия

Только что состоялся платный приём у врача. После консультации и сдачи анализов она выписала документ с указанием суммы стоимости оказанных услуг. Я предъявил этот документ в регистратуре платного отделения на кассе. Оплатил.

Какое наименование носит этот документ?

Comment: А что на нем сверху написано,, не удосужились посмотреть?

Comment: Можно сказать, что врач "выписал **счёт**" за оказанные услуги.

Comment: @Alex_ander - тогда уж счет-фактура. Или вовсе квитанция. Но все равно непонятно. Надуманная ситуация. Врачи давно все делают на компьютере... Походишь к ресепшену - и там платишь. А тебе распечатывают или шлют на почту счет-фактуру и прочее.

Comment: Квитанция - то, что _подтверждает_ факт оплаты (в отдельных случаях - отрывная часть документа), она бывает и отдельным документом. Счёт иногда бывает простой запиской для кассира, но в нём всегда информация, сколько платить.

Comment: Да, я и задумался, не квитанция ли это или чек. Но, так как мною услуги еще не были оплачены в момент выдачи этого документа, эти варианты отпали.

Comment: И после того как отпали, вы принимаете заведомо противоречащий этому положению ответ?!

Comment: Оказывается, квинтанция имеет более широкое значение, чем я предполагал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется "*квитанция для оплаты*".

Например: *квитанция для оплаты в банке*; *квитанция для оплаты на кассе*.

Примеры из финансовых справочников:

*Квитанция для оплаты разового сбора и платы за услуги в кассу в двух экземплярах*.

*Квитанция для оплаты сверхнормативного багажа.*

*Квитанция для оплаты через Сбербанк.*

*Все нарушения фиксируются камерами, а водителю по месту прописки отправляются фотография и квитанция для оплаты штрафа.*

Также существует "*квитанция об оплате*".